# Sort counted hits into separate files

Tags: string, text, sh

I have short.txt (contains strings) and a long.txt (contains strings).

For example short.txt contains:
this
that

long.txt contains: 
this
thisis
that
thisisan
thisisanexample

I have a source code which counts if a string from short.txt is in long.txt.

grep -F -o -f short.txt long.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr > counted.txt

So counted.txt will contain:
3 this
1 that

My question is: how can I get the results in separate files like:
3_this.txt (so number of hits+_+word+.txt)
(which contains)
this
thisis
thisisan
thisisanexample
1_that.txt
(which contains)
that

Small list can contain 10.000+ strings, the long list is 100.000.000+

I was playing with .sh because I can run it on my MAC with ease. Don't know if you have a faster solution for this.
The long.txt would be updated in every month, but the small.txt in every day.

Comment: `this` occurs 3 times, not 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Python Solution. This doesn't assume that you have created `counted.py`

```
import os

with open('short.txt', 'r') as shorttxt:
    for s in shorttxt:
        outfilename = s[:-1] + '.txt'
        count = 0
        with open('long.txt', 'r') as longtxt, open(outfilename, 'w') as out:
            for l in longtxt:
                if s[:-1] in l:
                    count += 1
                    out.write(l)
        os.rename(outfilename, str(count) + '_' + outfilename)
```

Comment: Much better. I would use `'{}_{}'.format(count, outfilename)` rather than `str()` and concatenation, but that's just style taste..

Comment: Thank you for your help. It runs faster. Let me know if you have an even faster method to check 10.000 (short) and 100.000.000 (long) list.

Answer (score 1):

All of this is a rather roundabout and inefficient way of achieving the result, but if you've done all that already and created `counted.txt`, you can use it to create the files you want:

```
while read count word; do
  grep -F "$word" long.txt >"${count}_${word}.txt"
done < counted.txt
```

But you're better off with a one-pass solution like Pulkit Agarwal's answer.

Comment: Thank you, it is working, and yes, it is kinda slow. The problem is that the long file is around 2Gb, the small is around 5-10mb, and I need to count the  hits, and also need to see the matching results. don't know is it possible to do it faster.